# Move Data from One Table To Another Table With New Layout

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Please note, I asked this previously, but realized that I left out some very important information and felt it better to remove the original question and post a new one.  My apologies to all........

I have a table that has the following columns:

```
ID
Name
2010/Jan
2010/Jan_pct
2010/Feb
2010/Feb_pct
.....
.....
2017/Nov
2017/Nov_pct
```

And then a column like that for every month/year combination to the present (hopefully that makes sense).  Please note though:  it is NOT a given that every month / year combination is present.  There might be a gap or a missing month/year.  For instance, I know 2017/Jan, 2017/Feb are missing and there could be any number missing.  I just didn't want to list out every column but give a general idea of the layout.

Added to that, there isn't one row in the database, but can have multiple rows for a Name / ID and the ID is not an identity, but can be any number.

To give an idea of how the table looks, here is some sample data (mind you, I only added two of the Year/Mon combinations, but there are dozens that do not necessarily have one for each month/year)

```
ID     Name    2010/Jan    2010/Jan_Pct  2010/Feb    2010/Feb_Pct
10     Gold    81          0.00123       79          0.01242
134    Silver  82          0             75          0.21291
678    Iron    987         1.53252       1056        2.9897
```

As you can imagine, this isn't the best design as you need to add a new two new columns every month. So I created a new table with the following definitions

```
ID - float, 
Name - varchar(255), 
Month - varchar(3), 
Year - int, 
Value - int, 
Value_Pct - float
```

I am trying to figure out how to move the existing data from the old table into the new table design.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.....

Comment: Might be better if you combine month and year into a single date column. Other than that the previous unpivot is what you need. Not sure why you deleted that one since 99.999% of the work was already done in that one.

Comment: Honest answer is because I thought I mistyped the requirements, but I saved the information.  It was my own stupidity for not fully understanding and got confused as a result, but I see what you are saying now.  My apologies for the mistake....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can work with the [`unpivot`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx) operator to get what you need, with one added step of combining extra rows returned by the `unpivot` operator.

**Sample Data Setup:**

Given that the destination table has a `value` column of `int` datatype and the `value_pct` of `float` data type, I followed the same datatype guidance for the existing data table.

```
create table dbo.data_table
    (
        ID float not null
        , [Name] varchar(255) not null
        , [2010/Jan] int null 
        , [2010/Jan_Pct] float null
        , [2010/Feb] int null
        , [2010/Feb_Pct] float null
    )

insert into dbo.data_table
values (10, 'Gold', 81, 0.00123, 79, 0.01242)
    , (134, 'Sliver', 82, 0, 75, 0.21291)
    , (678, 'Iron', 987, 1.53252, 1056, 2.9897)
```

**Answer:**

```
--combine what was the "value" row and the "value_pct" row
--into a single row via summation
select a.ID
, a.[Name]
, a.[Month]
, a.[Year]
, sum(a.value) as value
, sum(a.value_pct) as value_pct
from (
    --get the data out of the unpivot with one row for value
    --and one row for value_pct. 
    select post.ID
    , post.[Name]
    , substring(post.col_nm, 6, 3) as [Month]
    , cast(substring(post.col_nm, 1, 4) as int) as [Year]
    , iif(charindex('pct', post.col_nm, 0) = 0, post.value_prelim, null) as value
    , iif(charindex('pct', post.col_nm, 0) > 0, post.value_prelim, null) as value_pct
    from (
        --cast the columns that are currently INT as Float so that 
        --all data points can fit in one common data type (will separate back out later)
        select db.ID
        , db.[Name]
        , cast(db.[2010/Jan] as float) as [2010/Jan]
        , db.[2010/Jan_Pct]
        , cast(db.[2010/Feb] as float) as [2010/Feb]
        , db.[2010/Feb_Pct]
        from dbo.data_table as db
        ) as pre
    unpivot (value_prelim for col_nm in (
                                        [2010/Jan]
                                        , [2010/Jan_Pct]
                                        , [2010/Feb]
                                        , [2010/Feb_Pct]
                                        --List all the rest of the column names here
                                        )
            ) as post
    ) as a
group by a.ID
, a.[Name]
, a.[Month]
, a.[Year]
```

**Final Output:**

[image: Final Output]